# “Critical error on your website” Wordpress File Shifted

Tags: wordpress

My Problem is all the file and folder of wp-admin/wp-includes is shifted to wp-content folder automatically after certain period of time.
This is my website url : http://tech-webroyals.com/wp_v23_iqmass/
**this is my cpanel view of wp-content folder where all wp-admin file relocated**
Any help?[image: this is my cpanel view of wp-content folder where all wp-admin file relocated]

Comment: can you on error reporting? simply go to wp-config.php and set WP_DEBUG to true as this error may be due to number of reasons.

Comment: I check the debug section there is nothing . my problem is wp-admin/wp-includes is shifted to wp-content folder automatically after certain period of time.